# How to run Rust library unit tests with Maturin?

Tags: python, unit-testing, rust, maturin

I'm building a custom Python module in Rust, with maturin.

I am using PyEnv, with Python 3.12.2, installed with `env PYTHON_CONFIGURE_OPTS="--enable-shared"` and `--keep` so the Python sources are available. I have a venv and I'm using `maturin develop` to build my library and update the venv as I need to.

I have some unit tests in my `lib.rs` file, and usually I'd just run `cargo test` to run them.

But within the Maturin-managed environment, I get linker errors:

```
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
...
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: .../target/debug/deps/libpyo3-c286c2d4bbe22ea2.rlib(pyo3-c286c2d4bbe22ea2.pyo3.7555584b645de9e8-cgu.01.rcgu.o): in function `pyo3_ffi::object::Py_DECREF':
          $HOME/.cargo/git/checkouts/pyo3-a22e69bc62b9f0fd/da24f0c/pyo3-ffi/src/object.rs:597: undefined reference to `_Py_Dealloc'
```

I was able to work around this with the following two methods:

1. Using `RUSTFLAGS` and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` / rpath:

```
$ export RUSTFLAGS="-C link-arg=-Wl,-rpath,.../pyenv.git/versions/3.12.2/lib -C link-arg=-L.../pyenv.git/versions/3.12.2/lib -C link-arg=-lpython3.12"
```

2. Or creating `.cargo/config.toml`:

```
[target.'cfg(all())']
rustflags = [
    "-C", "link-arg=-Wl,-rpath,.../pyenv.git/versions/3.12.2/lib",
    "-C", "link-arg=-L.../pyenv.git/versions/3.12.2/lib",
    "-C", "link-arg=-lpython3.12",
]
```

I've snipped the paths for brevity/privacy.

Both of these methods are doing the same thing - providing an explicit linker path, library to link against, and run-time library path. This works, but it feels wrong.

I wasn't able to find a `maturin test` or equivalent, and it doesn't seem right that I have to manually specify the linker arguments to `cargo` / `rustc` when I have maturin right there to do that for me.

Is there a good way to do this with maturin?

---

EDIT: In the PyO3 docs I found the [Testing](https://pyo3.rs/v0.7.0-alpha.1/advanced.html#testing) section, which recommends converting this part of `Cargo.toml`:

```
[dependencies]
pyo3 = { git = "https://github.com/pyo3/pyo3", features = ["extension-module"] }
```

Into this:

```
[dependencies.pyo3]
git = "https://github.com/pyo3/pyo3"

[features]
extension-module = ["pyo3/extension-module"]
default = ["extension-module"]
```

And then running `cargo test --no-default-features`. This does in fact resolve the linker errors, but it still has trouble locating the library at runtime:

```
     Running unittests src/lib.rs (target/debug/deps/pyo3_example-cc3941bd091dc64e)
.../target/debug/deps/pyo3_example-cc3941bd091dc64e: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.12.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This is resolved with setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `.../pyenv.git/versions/3.12.2/lib`, so it goes some way to helping, but it's not quite sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty much the same setup: Python module with PyO3 and maturin. I run `cargo test` no problem. Maybe it's because in my `cargo.toml` I have this section:

```ini
[lib]
name = "module_name_whatever"
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]
```

EDIT: To help OP troubleshoot, here's my full Cargo.toml

```ini
[package]
name = "package_name"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[lib]
name = "package_name"
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]

[dependencies.pyo3]
version = "0.20.0"
# "abi3-py38" tells pyo3 (and maturin) to build using the stable ABI with minimum Python version 3.8
features = ["abi3-py38"]
```

Comment: I added `"lib"` to `crate_type` but alas, it still suffers the same linking problem. I wonder if it's mostly because I have a separate Python installation (using pyenv rather than /usr/bin/python), so the defaults for `cargo` aren't sufficient to locate the libraries to link against. Maybe in your case the defaults are OK.

Comment: I'm inside a python env as well; I never use `/usr/bin/python` for anything.

Is your env activated and did you `pip install maturin` _inside_ that environment?

Comment: Indeed. FWIW, `maturin develop` works perfectly, it's only `cargo test` that doesn't, presumably because that's a layer lower than maturin so it doesn't know how to find the Python libs for linking. If I provide them via `.cargo/config.toml` (or a few other ways) it works though. I don't have the python-dev package installed on my system either, in case that's being picked up by `rustc`.

Comment: Do you have your Python shared library (`.so`) in a custom location?

Comment: In my project, I'm not calling back out to Python from the Rust code, so maybe that's why it works without any special config on my part.

Comment: Nor am I - my project is super-simple, I just have a `#[pyfunction]` decorated "sum_as_string()" function that returns a PyResult of (a + b).to_string(), and a unit test in the same .rs file that calls this function. I think it has to link with Python because of the `pyfunction` and `pymodule` macros, and the use of `PyResult`. It's quite literally the PyO3 "Getting Started" project and hardly more. Strange eh?

Comment: What OS is this? I've added my full cargo.toml to my answer. I notice that you're grabbing pyo3 straight from git. I'm installing a specific version. And I have the `abi3-py38` feature. 

Note that I just run `cargo test` with nothing special. No flags or anything.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04. I will try a "clean" project with your config. I'm really not that far off that already but clearly something is different...

Answer (score -1):

Today is my first day working with maturin, so I’m no expert, but here are two ideas:

1. Try checking if conda (I use miniconda3) works where PyEnv isn’t working.
2. You could try using a Makefile or Just and get cargo watch to run make/just with a DAG that re-invokes maturin before it runs tests.